# Picker not selecting the desired option

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-picker

I am trying to setup a picker, simple. I am successfully fetching an array of projects from firebase and populating the picker with the names of the projects. The problem that I am having is that I need to get the project id when I click the list but it's not doing anything after I click the option that I want. I tried to run it in a simulator and also on my iPhone and nothing happens after I make the selection. I am pretty sure I am not updating the picker and thus I am not updating the variable with the selected project id. I tried using the .onChange on the picker but nothing happens.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewProjectView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ProjectViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var clientViewModel = ClientFeedViewModel()
    
    @Environment (\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var projectName: String = "s"
    
    var clientNameIsEmpty: Bool {
        if projectName.count < 3 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    var clients: [Client] {
        return clientViewModel.clients
    }
    
    @State var selectedClient: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                Picker("", selection: $selectedClient) {
                    ForEach(clients, id:\.self) {
                        Text($0.clientName)
                        //I need to exctract the project id so I can pass it on
                    }
                }
                .pickerStyle(.menu)
                
                CustomTextField(text: $projectName, placeholder: Text("Client Name"), imageName: "person.text.rectangle")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color("JUMP_COLOR")
                        .opacity(0.75)
                    )
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                Text("Name must contain more than 3 characters")
                    .font(.system(.subheadline))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.3))
                    .padding(.top, 30)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading, content: {
                            Button(action: {
                                dismiss()
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Cancel")
                            })
                        })
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing , content: {
                            Button(action: {
                                viewModel.newProject(name: projectName)
                                
                                dismiss()
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Save")
                            })
                            .disabled(clientNameIsEmpty)
                        })
                    }
            }
        }
        .presentationDetents([.height(400)])
        //.presentationDetents([.medium])
        .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
    }
}

struct NewProjectView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewProjectView()
    }
}
```

Here is the picker populated with the foo data: [picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26MUD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selection variable `$selectedClient` needs to have a type that matches the tagged value of each item in the picker.

As you're not specifying an explicit `.tag` for your text, the `ForEach` creates an implicit one using what it's using for tracking its loop, which in this case looks like it's a `Client`.

You can either change `selectedClient` to be a type of `Client`, or tag your displayed subview with the string value to populate `selectedClient` with, e.g.:

```swift
ForEach(clients, id: \.self) { client in
  Text(client.clientName)
    .tag(client.clientID)
}
```

Also, if each client has a unique ID, you're better off using that as ForEach's identifier than `\.self`. You can either specify `id: \.clientID`, etc., to use a single attribute – or you can add `Identifiable` conformance to `Client` and make sure that it has an `id` value that is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: thank you @ScottM, got it working... how could I post the code? this option only gives me about 500 characters

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct NewProjectView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = ProjectViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var clientViewModel = ClientFeedViewModel()
    
    @Environment (\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State var projectName: String = "s"
    
    var clientNameIsEmpty: Bool {
        if projectName.count < 3 {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
    
    var clients: [Client] {
        return clientViewModel.clients
    }
    
    @State var selectedClient: Client = Client(id: "", clientName: "Blank", timestamp: Timestamp(), ownerId: "", ownerUsername: "")
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                Picker("d", selection: $selectedClient) {
                    ForEach(clients, id:\.id) { client in
                        Text(client.clientName)
                            .tag(client)
                        
                        //I need to exctract the project id so I can pass it on
                    }
                    
                    
                }
                .pickerStyle(.menu)
                Text(selectedClient.id ?? "")
                
                CustomTextField(text: $projectName, placeholder: Text("Client Name"), imageName: "person.text.rectangle")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color("JUMP_COLOR")
                        .opacity(0.75)
                    )
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 40)
                Text("Name must contain more than 3 characters")
                    .font(.system(.subheadline))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray.opacity(0.3))
                    .padding(.top, 30)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading, content: {
                            Button(action: {
                                dismiss()
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Cancel")
                            })
                        })
                        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing , content: {
                            Button(action: {
                                viewModel.newProject(name: projectName)
                                
                                dismiss()
                            }, label: {
                                Text("Save")
                            })
                            .disabled(clientNameIsEmpty)
                        })
                    }
            }
        }
        .presentationDetents([.height(400)])
        //.presentationDetents([.medium])
        .presentationDragIndicator(.visible)
    }
}

struct NewProjectView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewProjectView()
    }
}
```